# How to construct a binary sequence whose limiting relative frequency of 1s equals a given real number?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

For any $x=x_1x_2x_3...\in\{0,1\}^\infty$, let $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$.

Given any real $p\in(0,1)$, I want to generate a binary sequence $x$ such that $\ \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=p.$

If $p$ is rational, say $p=\frac{a}{b}$ in lowest terms, then I can  take $x=(1^a0^{b-a})^\infty$ (in string notation), because $f_n(x)$ is then either exactly $p$ or is bounded above and below by terms converging to $p$.

**Question**: If $p$ is *irrational*, how can I generate infinite sequences $(a_i)$ and $(b_i)$ such that the concatenation $x=(1^{a_1}0^{b_1-a_1})(1^{a_2}0^{b_2-a_2})(1^{a_3}0^{b_3-a_3})...\ $ satisfies $\ \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=p$?

Comment: Not important, but you could simplify the notation and not require people to look things up: In the present context $[x_i=1] = x_i$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich - Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x_1$ be $0$ or $1$, doesn't matter. Suppose you've chosen $x_1,\dots,x_n$, so that $f_n$ is defined. If $f_n\ge p$ let $x_{n+1}=0$, otherwise let $x_{n+1}=1$.

Comment: (+1) I don't know why I didn't think of this!

Comment: +1: This is disarmingly simple and transparent procedure! I was thinking I'd a nice elementary construction not appealing to any theorem.

Answer (score 2):

You could let $f(x)=\sum_{n>0} 2^{-n} [ (nx\bmod 1)<p ]$, which is to say, the real number whose $n$-th binary digit is a $1$ if $nx \bmod 1\in [0,p)$, and $0$ otherwise.  If $x$ is irrational it is known that the fractional parts of $nx$ are equidistibuted, which implies the limiting fraction of $1$ digits is what you want it to be.

Comment: Ah, nice. So, in the notation of the question, I could take for example,  $x_n=\left[\left\{n\sqrt{2}\right\}\in[0,p)\right]$, where $\{.\}$ denotes fractional part. (I would still be interested in knowing how sequences $(a_i)$ and $(b_i)$ might be found more directly, though.)

Comment: Yes.  I think you could take $a_n=\lfloor n \alpha\rfloor$ and $b_n=\lfloor n \beta\rfloor$ for irrational $\alpha$ and $\beta$, chosen carefully to get your desired proportions.

Answer (score 2):

I will describe an iterative procedure  that will have at the end of $k$ rounds the first $10^k$ terms of the binary sequence.

The next iteration will use this as the base, and provide the first $10^{k+1}$ terms.

Write your real number in decimal system  (assumed to be between 0 and 1). Take the $k+1$th digit after the decimal point.

Given the base of $10^k$ terms from the inductive step we will use it  9 more times, either without any change or with a single change, ending up  $10^{k+1}$ terms totally. *Using* means appending and enlarging our sequence.

The single change is always: take the base block and replace the final 0 in it by a 1.

How many times we append a modified base block or use it unmodiefied? Simple: the $k+1$-th decimal of the given real number specifies how many times we modify.

Example: Assume the first two decimals are 0.62.

Initial block of 10 terms is six one's followed by four 0's.

1111110000
This is the base for round 2, denote it it by $B$
Modifed version is 1111110001 (the final zero changed to 1) denote it by $B'$.

Now at the end of round 2 we will have the concatenation:
$BB'B'BBBBBBB$. And this will form the base block for the next iteration.

Comment: Excellent! I think your procedure can be summarized as follows: For any real $p=(0.d_1d_2...)_{10}$, let $B_1=1^{d_1}0^{10-d_1},\ B_{k+1}=(B_k^\prime)^{d_k}B_k^{10-d_k}$, where $B_k^\prime$ is $B_k$ with its last $0$ changed to $1$. Then $B_k$ has length $10^k$ and the number of $1$s it contains is found to be $d_110^{k-1}+d_210^{k-2}+...+d_k10^0$; so, indeed, the relative frequency of $1$s in $B_k$ is $(0.d_1d_2...d_k)_{10}$, converging to $p$ just as required. (I put all the primed $B$s at the beginning of each $B_k$, but that has no ill effect.)

Comment: You have got that right.  Remember I just went naturally with newer decimals giving fine tuning.. The advantage of this method is being elementary, and making no distinction between rational and irrationals; no need to know about equidistribution theorems

Comment: It's beautiful in its simplicity, and, in fact, just the kind of procedure I had in mind. (Obviously, I wasn't aiming for a "random looking" sequence, which is what use of the equidistribution theorem seems likely to produce.)

Comment: @ r.e.s. If you find this helpful, you can accept my answer!

Comment: As much as I like this answer, currently my vote has to go to [the one by David Ullrich](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2529401/16397).